# How to draw writable rectangles on images using JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

[Liveworksheets](https://www.liveworksheets.com/) is a website for students and teachers where teachers can upload files with questions then after uploading the file the teacher answers these questions and then send this file to students -without answers of course- to answer it. There are many ways that can teacher use to solve these questions but the way that matters to me is the teacher can draw rectangles on an image and then write the answer on it.

**My Question Is:**
How I Can draw writable rectangles on the image using javascript?

see the [demo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y27sEzC0_CS8BzjaG3CpIdpHmrlcx-09/view?usp=sharing) for clarity.

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: I have converted the image to canvas then I give the teacher permission to draw rectangles but not writable, but when I opened the developer tool on this website I found the website's creator uses image NOT canvas, and now I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY, after a long of searching, I found [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/), here is an example of my code

```
let fabricCanvas = new fabric.Canvas('your-canvas-id');

// You can change the canvas size via the next two lines
fabricCanvas.setHeight(document.getElementById('your-image').height);
fabricCanvas.setWidth(document.getElementById('your-image').width);

fabric.Image.fromURL(document.getElementById('your-image').src, function (img) {
    let textBox = new fabric.Textbox("Enter Your Answer", {
            fontSize: 16,
            fontFamily: 'Arial',
            textAlign: 'left',
            width: 180,
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
        });

    fabricCanvas.add(img.set({ left: 0, top: 0 }));
    fabricCanvas.add(textBox);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Konva js is a nice bet.

https://konvajs.org/

This tool allows you create shapes, and save everything to a database so you can reload all drawings to future usage.

Nice try

Comment: Yep, it's very nice but the shapes that create are not writeable for sorry